# Euler First Substitution

Tags: integration

Q: How can I see the idea that Euler followed to get his substitution for
$$\int R(x, \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}) dx$$
to be $\sqrt{ax^2+ax+c} = \sqrt{a}x + t$?

My approach is to put

$$\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} = \alpha x + \beta t + \gamma$$

Maybe Euler wished to dispose of the square root by making the whole expression linear, as you may see. Either way, I got

$$(\alpha^2-a)x^2 + (2\alpha \beta t + 2\alpha \gamma - b)x + \beta^2 t^2 + 2\beta \gamma t + \gamma^2 - c = 0$$

The advantage of the substitution over my ordinary one

$$\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c} = \alpha t + \beta$$

is that we do not have to solve quadratic equation to determine the unknown $x$. For this purpose, I must set

$$\alpha^2 - a = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha = \pm \sqrt{a}$$

Then

$$x = \frac{c - \beta^2 t^2 - 2\beta \gamma t -\gamma^2}{2\alpha \beta t + 2\alpha \gamma - b}$$

For simplicity,it is desired to suppose that $\gamma = 0$ and $\beta = 1$, so the formula becomes

$$x = \frac{c - t^2}{2t\sqrt{a} - b}$$

From this, I get

$$dx = \frac{2t^2\sqrt{a}- 2bt+2c\sqrt{a}}{(2t\sqrt{a} -b)^2}dt$$

That is considerably better to use the kind of substitution than

$$t\sqrt{a} - \frac{b}{2} = \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$$

However, using the last one also helps to solve

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}$$

My derivation is what I think How Euler might have derived its substitution. Still curious about to remember his substitutions.

Comment: Lilewise, I may consider another function $\psi(x,t)$ such that $$\psi = \alpha xt + \beta = \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$$. Then I wish to get rid of quadratic equation, so there must be $\beta^2 - c = 0$. The third Euler substitution is somewhat obvious but looks like $$\alpha xt + \beta t + \gamma x + \delta = \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$$. Here I should try. However, I do not understand logic of the substitutions in order to keep them in mind.

Comment: This page https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EulersSubstitutionsForTheIntegralOfAParticularFunction/ has some insight on the subject

Comment: @Vasya now I understand from where Euler substitutions come. Thank you!